# Accidently ran shortcut key combo for org-columns in org mode emacs and now want to get rid of column view at the top of the buffer

Tags: emacs, org-mode

As stated accidently ran the org-column command and I manage to remove it from the todo item somehow. Not sure how but it got rid of it but it's still at the top of the buffer it shows the column labels. How do I remove this and remove org-column view from a todo item in the future if this happens again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, hitting <kbd>q</kbd> anywhere on a column is equivalent to `M-x org-columns-quit RET`.

Comment: Figured that out looking at @kindahero link below

Answer (score 3):

Figured out you have to run the command:

```
org-columns-quit
```

Comment: column-view is little confusing when you don't know what it is for. But please remember it is extremely useful for editing properties. you may need it some day.

Comment: @kindahero - yes, I messed with it a little bit when it was up there and if you had a lot of properties it could make it extremely quick so I was glad I accidently did it but just at first was confused what happend. Is there a keyboard shortcut for org-columns-quit by default? It didn't seem like it.

Comment: There is a way to get out or do lot more. please see the manual entry http://orgmode.org/org.html#Using-column-view and tutorial on worg http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-column-view-tutorial.html